# Python/Kivy Screen Transition

Tags: python, class, kivy

In Kivy for Python I am wondering how you can schedule a screen to automatically transition to a new screen after a specified number of seconds. I scheduled an event with the Kivy Clock tool, but it is unresponsive to my code when I run the application. Here is my main.py code:

```
class Opening_Screen():

       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
              super(Opening_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
              Clock.schedule_once(self.change_screen, 5)

       def change_screen(self, *kwargs):
              root.current = 'Options_Screen'


class Patient_Care(App):
     pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

     Patient_Care().run()
```

Here is my corresponding .kv file code:

```
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import RiseInTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.RiseInTransition


ScreenManager:
     transition: RiseInTransition()

      Screen: 
           name: 'Opening_Screen'

           Label:
               text:'Welcome'
               font_size: 40 
               color: 0, 0, 1, 1 
               pos:(self.x / 2, 250) 

           Button:
               size_hint: (1, None)
               height: 90
               font_size: 30
               background_normal: 'button_normal.png'
               background_down: 'button_down.png'
               border: (2, 2, 2, 2)
               text: 'Continue'
               on_press: root.current = 'Options_Screen'





      Screen:
           name: 'Options_Screen'

           GridLayout:
               padding: 15
               rows: 5
               spacing: 10

               Button:
                   text:'Option 1'

               Button:
                   text:'Option 2'

               Button: 
                   text: 'Option 3'

               Button:
                   text: 'Option 4'

               Button:
                   text: 'Option 5'
```

In my .kv file I have another screen called the "Options_Screen". I want to switch from the "Opening_Screen" to the options screen after 5 seconds. The transition works when I create a button for the Opening_Screen and design it to switch to the Options_Screen (on_press: root.current = 'Options_Screen'). However, my goal is to switch automatically without a Button press using the Clock.schedule_once function to dynamically switch.

Comment: show your .kv!!!!

Comment: What class does the Opening_Screen inherit?

Comment: What is your .kv name?

Comment: my .kv name is patient_care.kv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not show the code necessary to reproduce your error, for example the application must end in App, and the name of the .kv must be the remaining part of the class in lowercase. Another possible error is that Opening_Screen does not inherit of any kind so it will probably never be called, etc.

So I will just provide an example:

**patientcare.kv**

```
ScreenManager
    Opening_Screen:
        name: 'Opening_Screen'
    Options_Screen:
        name: 'Options_Screen'


<Opening_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Opening_Screen'

<Options_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Options_Screen'
```

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Opening_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Opening_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.change_screen, 5)

    def change_screen(self, *kwargs):
        self.manager.current = 'Options_Screen'

class Options_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class PatientCareApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PatientCareApp().run()
```

## Update1:

As you added more code you just have to map the new class:

***.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Opening_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Opening_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.change_screen, 5)
    def change_screen(self, *kwargs):
        self.manager.current = 'Options_Screen'


class Patient_Care(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Patient_Care().run()
```

***.kv**

```
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import RiseInTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.RiseInTransition

<Opening_Screen>:

ScreenManager:
    transition: RiseInTransition()
    Opening_Screen: 
        name: 'Opening_Screen'
[...]
```

## Update2:

If you do not want to implement it in a Screen you can do it in the App.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock


class Patient_Care(App):
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.change_screen, 5)

    def change_screen(self, *kwargs):
        self.root.current = 'Options_Screen'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Patient_Care().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question to include the .kv file. Is it necessary that I pass Screen in the Class creation? I was trying to avoid having my classes inherit from the Screen class, and I assumed that the opening screen would still be able to make an automatic transition if I created a function specifically for that.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo Is that if you realize you are trying Opening_Screen be the one that uses the Clock, but the Opening_Screen that is in your .py is different from the .kv. How do you think they are linked?

Comment: Would there be a way to schedule an automatic transition in the .kv screen that I created. That would've been a better question. My mistake was that I thought that if I created a class in the .py file that matched the name in the .kv file, they would automatically bind. You're right, that won't work. So would there be a way to have the screen transition from the .kv file?

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo you can not create a Clock in the .kv, but I think it can be done in PatientCareApp

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo Check my last update, maybe it's what you're looking for